# pdfbox document is encrypted error

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I have a [pdf document](http://sdrv.ms/WoimbF) which I am parsing with pdfbox. The document is not encrypted, I can open the document. However, following lines of code from PDFBox

```
    try
        {
            document = PDDocument.load( inpFilename);


            if( document.isEncrypted() )
            {
                System.err.println( "Error: Document is encrypted with a password." );
                return;

            }
```

creates the error: `"Error: Document is encrypted with a password."`. Any idea why is that happening? Are there various kinds of pdf encryption (allows you to read, but not process with pdfbox)?

Comment: To add, pdfimages can operate on the pdf, creating images.

Comment: Being able to open a document e.g. in adobe reader does not mean the document is not encrypted. Unfortunately I only have my cellular phone at hand and can not check your PDF but I would guess your document is encrypted using the default user password...

Comment: Your link, when it initially worked, allowed to download two documents, AN9780300883.pdf and b303635a.pdf, which one do you have problems with? The former one is not encrypted but the latter one is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the answer here: [remove encryption from pdf with pdfbox, like qpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700241/remove-encryption-from-pdf-with-pdfbox-like-qpdf/14700523#14700523)

Shows you how to easily decrypt the document if there is no user password specified.