# Remove encryption from PDF file using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

With [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/), you can simply remove *restrictions / encryption* from a PDF file like so:

```
qpdf --decrypt infile outfile
```

I would like to do the same thing with [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) in Java:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFilename);
if (doc.isEncrypted()) {
   // remove the encryption to alter the document
}
```

I've tried this with [`StandardDecryptionMaterial`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/encryption/StandardDecryptionMaterial.html), but I have no idea what the owner password is. How does QPDF does this?

Sample document:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12514714/in.pdf

Comment: Depending on the type of encryption of the PDF it is easy to decrypt (how else to display it). It beats the concept of this encryption, though, to allow anyone without some authorisation (owner password) to remove the encryption. If you have encrypted PDF files and don't have the owner password, you are expected to turn to the document owner if you require an unencrypted version.

Answer (score 26):

This is what you'd need to do (inspired from the PDFBox [WriteDecodedDoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#writedecodeddoc) command line tool):

```
if (doc.isEncrypted()) {
    try {
        doc.decrypt("");
        doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("The document is encrypted and we can't decrypt it.", e);
    }
}
```

Note: you *may* have to include the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) JAR.

Comment: This is the deprecated API. Please use the new API as outlined at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29676262/873282.

Comment: there is not such a method doc.decrypt() -  it's enough to use doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);