# pdfbox: trying to decrypt PDF

Tags: java, encryption, pdfbox

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700241/remove-encryption-from-pdf-with-pdfbox-like-qpdf) I'm trying to decrypt a pdf-document with pdfbox:

```
PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load(path);
if(pd.isEncrypted()){
    try {
        pd.decrypt("");
        pd.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("The document is encrypted, and we can't decrypt it.");
    }
```

This leads to

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.openProtection(PDDocument.java:1601)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.decrypt(PDDocument.java:948)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
...
```

The path is correct, so I don't know what's going on.
Furthermore, if I have a look at the PDDocument.decrypt(String pw) method, I find this:
*This will decrypt a document. This method is provided for compatibility reasons only. User should use the new security layer instead and the openProtection method especially.*

What does it mean? Could someone give an example how to decrypt a pdf-document correctly with pdfbox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the dependency list:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html

You need to use the bouncycastle libraries.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
  <version>1.44</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
  <version>1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

the decrypt() call is indeed deprecated in the current version (1.8.9). Use

```
pd.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(""));
```

instead.

Additional advice: download the source code package. You'll find many examples that will help you further.

Comment: Good point about downloading the source code.  There is a command line tool `Decrypt` here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.4/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/Decrypt.html.  This will be useful to study!

Answer (score 7):

To use the `openProtection` method you have to provide an instance of `DecryptionMaterial`. In your case of password protection it would be StandardDecryptionMaterial (from the [API](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.9/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/encryption/StandardDecryptionMaterial.html)):

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(in);  
StandardDecryptionMaterial dm = new   StandardDecryptionMaterial("password");
doc.openProtection(dm);
```

Furthermore, you have to fullfil the Bouncy Castle dependency of PDFBox for using Encryption/Signing. See https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html.

Comment: No method `openProtection` in new PDFBox. You need to use `load(file, password)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580148/pdfbox-2-0-0-decryption-using-password/36580428#36580428