# PDFBox 2.0.0 - decryption using password

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to unlock a PDF using a password with PDFBox 2.0.0.

In 1.8.11 I was using the [PDDocument.openProtection(DecryptionMaterial pm)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.6/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.java#PDDocument.openProtection%28org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.DecryptionMaterial%29) method but it was removed in [2.0.0](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/) from what I see.

The [online documentation](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/cookbook/encryption.html) does not say how this can be achived in 2.0.0.

## Question:

The PDF unlocking with password is still possible in PDFBox 2.0.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 2.0, you just call `PDDocument.load(file, password)` or `PDDocument.load(file)` (if the password is empty). You don't have to call `openProtection()` anymore. The `load()` of 2.0 call is similar to the `loadNonSeq()` call of 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

I used the latest version with the following code:

```
  PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load(ResourceUtils.getFile("[Your_File_Path]"), "[Your_Password]");
  pd.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
  pd.save("[New_FileName.pdf]");
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.68</version>
    </dependency>
```